# How to discern the package's subprogram types in ALL_PROCEDURES table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Querying the `ALL_PROCEDURES` table in Oracle can return all subprograms of a given package. For such use case the `object_type` column has value `PACKAGE`. How to discern whether the object behind `procedure_name` is a procedure, function, trigger or type method?

Comment: you want the dependecies of the procedure ?

Comment: no, I want to have use cases like list all procedures of a given package.

Comment: you want to know what are the procedures followed in a package ?

Comment: yes, doing java coding through sql queries. getting all packages, then all its procedures, functions, type methods and printing it in some hierarchy. I don't see how could I discern in `all_procedures` what is the concrete type of a package's subprogram, i.e. function of procedure.

Comment: my answer not what you need ?

Comment: You  might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672956/why-procedures-view-doesnt-show-the-procedure-name

Comment: @Moudiz No it doesn't. Try it yourself. Name in `all_dependencies` corresponds to `object_name` in `all_procedures`. This means your query won't contain any data about the package members. And my question is precisely about package members types. As for now `all_procedures` lists the members of the package, but without their precise type. All I know is that these are subprograms. Simple example: user: `SYS`, package: `DBMS_ADR`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the depenencides of the procedures ? if yes check the below query

```
select * from user_dependencies where name ='TABLE_ME'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check what sqldeveloper does when I expand a package in schema browser. 
It seems it does:

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM SYS.Dba_SOURCE
WHERE TYPE = :TYPE AND OWNER = :OWNER AND NAME = :NAME
ORDER BY LINE;
```

So it appears that actually just grabs the code then it parse it to list the objects in the package...