# Saving a new procedure in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, plsql, compilation, oracle-sqldeveloper

If we create a new procedure using Oracle SQL Developer, suppose TESTPROC

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS 
BEGIN
 --SOMETHING
END TESTPROC;
```

and just save it using CTRL+S and don't run it, will it not be saved as procedure? if we close the window and try to search for it in list of procedures, we cant find it?

Do we need to run the proc at least once to save it?

Any way to retrieve a procedure lost this way?

Comment: "try to search for it in list of procedures"... you mean search for it in the oracle table system ?

Comment: You must **compile** the procedure to save it in the disk. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try to search for it in list of procedures

this query tells you if your procedure exists on your database

```
select * from user_procedures where object_name ='THE NAME OF YOUR PROC'
```

Or

```
select * from user_objects where object_type ='PROCEDURE' and OBJECT_NAME='THE NAME OF YOUR PROC'
```

to solve error  `object already exists` add `or replace` in your procedure like this

`create or replace procedure Proc_test ...`

Comment: To add more... For stand alone procedures use `object_name` and for procedures wrapped inside package use `procedure_name`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672956/why-procedures-view-doesnt-show-the-procedure-name

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+S - you save a file. You can find this file in your OS.

To save procedure in DB you must create it in DB. For this you need execute `CREATE PROCEDURE`. So no, you didn't "save" it in DB.

Comment: when I am trying to create a new procedure of the same name, i get error object already exists. But cant find it if i filter the procedures of the same name. How to retrieve the existing one?

Comment: use "refresh" button in SQL developer

Answer (score 2):

> just save it using CTRL+S and don't run it, will it not be saved as procedure?

**Oracle SQL Developer** is an **IDE** and NOT the database server. It provides an **interface** to interact with **database**. `CTRL + S` is Windows OS shortcut and has nothing to do with Oracle database.

You must **compile** the procedure to store it into the disk.

[You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625040/saving-a-new-procedure-in-sqldeveloper#comment55024052_33625099),

> when I am trying to create a new procedure of the same name, i get error object already exists

That is because you are not using the `REPLACE` keyword to override the existing object.

**Let's see why:**

```
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE foo
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE foo
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

**How to avoid it:** Use `CREATE OR REPLACE`

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.
```

To see whether the compiled procedure exists in the database, query the **[DBA|ALL|USERS]_PROCEDURES** view.

There are two things:

- **Stand alone procedures** - use `object_name` as filter

```
SELECT owner,
  object_name,
  procedure_name,
  object_type
FROM all_procedures
WHERE owner    ='OWNER'
AND object_name='PROC_NAME';
```

- **Packaged procedures**    - use `procedure_name` as filter

```
SELECT owner,
  object_name,
  procedure_name,
  object_type
FROM all_procedures
WHERE owner    ='OWNER'
AND procedure_name='PROC_NAME';
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

PLSQL Developer or any other client is just a tool for you to talk to the database itself. You might be using Toad, sql* or any other interface, and they may all have their own way of doing things.

What you call *running*, is actually called ***compiling***. When you "run" the statement you provided, it is only compiled against the database you are connected to. It can only actually run, if you call the procedure you compiled from a PLSQL block.

Try to understand the differences between a database server and an IDE, then you'll be a lot more comfortable working with Oracle.

Comment: when I am trying to create a new procedure of the same name, i get error object already exists. But cant find it if i filter the procedures of the same name. How to retrieve the existing one?

Comment: @user2093576 Use `CREATE OR REPLACE` so that you don't get object already exists error.