# View from Oracle in Entity Framework not adding. Not primary key

Tags: sql, entity-framework, view, oracle11g

I am facing issues to add a view from oracle to entity framework.

First, the error was that can not infer a primary key from the colums, so I add a pk to the view.

Now says that primary key is not valid because a part of it is nullable.

Oracle query:

```
CREATE VIEW ALERTEST."GET_SPMONITORES"
AS
     select
     CAST(NVL(procedure_name, '')AS VARCHAR(200)) AS SP
     from all_procedures
     where object_name = 'PAC_NL_MONITORES' AND procedure_name IS NOT  NULL
;

ALTER VIEW GET_SPMONITORES 
ADD CONSTRAINT GET_SPMONITORES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SP) DISABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: Btw, in Oracle `''` and `NULL` are one and the same.

Comment: Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28672956/861716) you could probably use `NVL(procedure_name, object_name)` (or coalesce), or filter out the procedures that are not in a package.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same issue, trying to load a VIEW into EF with Oracle doing its best to wreck all of my tests in making a column show as NOT NULL.

I finally was able to do so using this.

Create a new table

```
 CREATE TABLE "KEY_TABLE" 
   (    "MY_KEY" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "KEY_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MY_KEY")
   );

INSERT INTO KEY_TABLE (MY_KEY) VALUES (1);
```

Then, create a VIEW that will have both your original view and this new table

```
 CREATE VIEW "GET_SPMONITORES_KEY"
AS
     select
        my_key, sp
      from key_table, GET_SPMONITORES
      where my_key = 1
```

This will then give you a view :

```
describe "GET_SPMONITORES_KEY";

Name   Null     Type          
------ -------- ------------- 
MY_KEY NOT NULL NUMBER        
SP              VARCHAR2(200)
```

You can now import this GET_SPMONITORES_KEY into EF and thoroughly ignore the my_key column afterwards. You will be able to use this view in any LINQ to SQL statements without any issues.

I have a view that returns the id (PK) of 3 separate tables and I'm able to link them to their corresponding tables in my LINQ to SQL statements so I can return their corresponding EntityObjects.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat here a little bit.  You don't have to have a primary key defined in the database.  You do, however, need to define the primary key inside Entity Framework for the POCO.  Thus, you could just figure out what uniquely identifies a record and then mark the fields that are part of that primary key with either [Key] attribute on the POCO or via Fluent API.  If you are auto generating this with T4 templates, you'd have to manually add that to the Fluent API only.

If you're primary key is incorrect, though, it will crash if two records end up with the same key.

A primary key cannot be a nullable field, however.  If there is no possible way to uniquely identify this data, I would just return a new Guid() in the view and just rely on that being unique to get around this.  Though, I'm not entirely sure how you are using this data, so not sure if that would be a problem in the future.

Comment: I am adding it by EF designer from database.
I add a new guid, but still not working

Comment: You have to change the generated code for this view.  You cannot define a primary key on a view.  Thus, EF won't be able to work with that view.  The only way around that is to manually tell EF what the PK is in code.  The generator isn't going to know/produce code that has a PK in it.